# Why won't Jaguar start after brakes failed?

Tags: brakes, starting, ignition, brake-fluid, jaguar

2012 Jaguar XF had 4 pads/rotors replaced and I returned to shop explaining they were less responsive and required extra pressure to stop and to remain stopped.  The shop looked at it and said they fixed but while driving I needed to stop hard.  Hard enough for anti-lock to kick in, which it didn't, and instead the car pulled to the right, and the front left wheel area popped and smoked.  I drove it 1 mile back to the shop and left it for them to fix.

The next day, it wouldn't start.  Headlights and dash illuminate, but no ignition initiation.  Error message on dash says BRAKE FLUID LOW.  The shop filled brake fluid and it drained right out on the spot.  There had been no leakage when I had it back home the first time. I tried both fobs and inserted it.  Diagnostic scan results show error code B1009-63 (Ignition authorization - Circuit/Component Protection Timeout).

I'm thinking: wrong equipment installed, no brake fluid, maximum pressure, then burst brake line.  But, what else could be going on?

So, it's obviously not at the dealership which is why I'm posting here.  It's at a local shop I've used for 8 years, but this is over their heads, and I don't trust them without verifying.  Yes, I'll probably take it to Jaguar afterwards for inspection, but they're paying for related issues, right?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: A simple pads+rotors change should not have caused all of those issues but then again, it is a Jaguar (luxury car) so unfortunately anything is possible. If there is a special procedure for resetting the caliper piston and the shop was not aware of it then it's quite possible your system is screwed up now. You get what you pay for...